# escaping spaces in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-scripting

```
yesterday="2010-06-23 00:00:00"
today="2010-06-24 00:00:00"
mywhere="lastupdate>'$yesterday' and lastupdate<'$today'"

mysqldump $param ticket --no-create-info --where=\"$mywhere\"
```

The last line of above shell script would return something like this...

```
+ mysqldump -uroot -d --compact ahmadpur ticket --no-create-info --where="lastupdate>'2010-06-23 00:00:00' and lastupdate<'2010-06-24 00:00:00'"
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "00:00:00'"
```

There is an error in the mysqldump command execution. But if I copy paste the same line, it runs successfully.
Do I need to escape the spaces in shell script output? if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysqldump $param ticket --no-create-info --where="$mywhere"
```

(do not escape double quotes in `--where="$mywhere"`)